# find the pattern in this number sequence of 1's and 0's

Tags: code-golf, sequence, kolmogorov-complexity

Write the shortest program or function which generates these 1000 numbers or a sequence (0- or 1-indexed) which begins with them.

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
```

Comment: this is my first time posting a code puzzle.  if you have any style improvements.  let me know.

Comment: Hi John, and welcome to PPCG!  Challenges here need to have an objective win condition (usually code-golf).  We also recommend running all challenges through the [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) before posting.

Comment: As the goal of this problem seems to be finding the sequence, I'd recommend asking for the shortest code that will generate these first 1000 elements correctly.

Comment: @Mnemonic that sounds about right.  My code is already quite short, and I'm asking if there's an even shorter code.  Feel free to edit :-) or I can just move to sandbox

Comment: I forget who did this challenge before. But it was very well received to "find the pattern". I vaguely remember someone cracking it in 50 minutes; but people continued to answer even after that.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>11</s> 10 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

*Saved 1 byte thanks to @Dennis*

```
ȷḶ×⁽q£:ȷ5Ḃ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR0A4v9qZWxsef//yLfhuLbDl@KBvXHCozrItzXhuIL//w)

#### How?

I first noticed that the pattern alternates between runs of length 4 and length 3, skipping the length-4 step every few runs. This led me to look for a number which could be divided into the current index, then taken mod 2 and floored—i.e. retrieving the least significant bit—to give the bit at that index in the series. After much trial and error, I found that `3.41845` does exactly that, but multiplying by its approximate reciprocal (`.29253`) is a byte shorter.

```
ȷḶ×⁽q£:ȷ5Ḃ    Main link. Arguments: none
ȷ             Yield 1e3, i.e. 1000.
 Ḷ            Lowered range; yield [0, 1, 2, ..., 999].
  ×⁽q£        Multiply each item by 29253.
      :ȷ5     Floor-divide each item by 1e5, i.e. 100000.
         Ḃ    Take each item mod 2.
```

Comment: ah you found it

Comment: [0...999] times each by 0.2925, mod 2 and floor (I'd go floor then mod 2 but equivalent)

Comment: Well that's quite anticlimactic, was expecting something more intricate.

Comment: @JonathanAllan I originally tried just `Ḃ` but apparently that's just mod 2 rather than lowest bit, so I added the `Ḟ` to fix it. Swapped now

Comment: Could stick with integers all the way too: `ȷḶ×117:400Ḃ`

Comment: @JonathanAllan That doesn't quite work, unfortunately. If it did, it could be shortened to `ȷḶ×⁽¡ʋ:4ȷḂ`.

Comment: `ȷḶ×⁽q£:ȷ5Ḃ` works, for 10 bytes.

Comment: @johnmangual Any particular reason for this number 3.41845? I first misread it as pi (3.141592...), which would have been kinda neat.

Answer (score 6):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>34 29 26</s> 22 bytes

```ruby
$.+=184while p$./629%2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/X0VP29bQwqQ8IzMnVaFARU/fzMhS1ej/fwA)

Quick explanation: this works because of the magic number 629. I noticed that the sequence starts repeating after the 629th element, and I tried to "improve" some existing answer, using only integer math. I found that the other "magic number" (0.29253) is actually 184/629.

Answer (score 3):

## [Dyalog APL](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>99</s> <s>83</s> 82 bytes

```apl
a←{⍵/0 1}¨(↓3 2⍴4 3 3)
{a⊢←↓⍉↑a{⍺∘{⍵/⊂⍺}¨⍵}¨↓3 3⍴⍵}¨(9/5)∘⊤¨1386531 496098
1000⍴∊a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ooz3tf@KjtgnVj3q36hsoGNYeWqHxqG2ysYLRo94tJgrGCsaaXNWJj7oWAdUAxR/1dj5qm5gIVL3rUccMsKZHXU1AHlAfkAMiQZqNgZohXA1LfVNNoNJHXUsOrTA0tjAzNTZUMLE0M7C04DI0MDAAKezoSgQ55H8aAA)

Definitely not the intended solution as this still has a lot of hardcoded data, but it's a start.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 31 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

Given the pattern there is probably an even shorter way...

```
ĖŒṙḂ
“ṁ⁽⁺ḄæI’BḤ+3żḂ$ẎÇo2Ç+3Çḣȷ¬
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AUkAtv9qZWxsef//xJbFkuG5meG4ggrigJzhuYHigb3igbrhuITDpknigJlC4bikKzPFvOG4giThuo7Dh28yw4crM8OH4bijyLfCrP//)**

#### How?

Exploits the repeating run length structure that is apparent to a depth of three.

```
ĖŒṙḂ - Link 1, make runs of bits: list of lengths    e.g. [5,3,5,3,3]
Ė    - enumerate                      [[1,5],[2,3],[3,5],[4,3],[5,3]]
 Œṙ  - run-length decode      [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5]
   Ḃ - bit (modulo by 2)      [1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1]

“ṁ⁽⁺ḄæI’BḤ+3żḂ$ẎÇo2Ç+3Çḣȷ¬ - Main link: no arguments
“ṁ⁽⁺ḄæI’                   - literal 234931870193324
        B                  - to binary = [1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0]
         Ḥ                 - double    = [2,2,0,2,0,2,0,2,2,0,2,0,2,0,2,2,0,2,0,2,0,2,2,0,2,0,2,0,2,0,2,2,0,2,0,2,0,2,2,0,2,0,2,0,2,2,0,0]
          +3               - add three = [5,5,3,5,3,5,3,5,5,3,5,3,5,3,5,5,3,5,3,5,3,5,5,3,5,3,5,3,5,3,5,5,3,5,3,5,3,5,5,3,5,3,5,3,5,5,3,3]
              $            - last two links as a monad:
             Ḃ             -   bit     = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
            ż              -   zip     = [[5,1],[5,1],[3,1],[5,1],[3,1],[5,1],[3,1],[5,1],[5,1],[3,1],[5,1],[3,1],[5,1],[3,1],[5,1],[5,1],[3,1],[5,1],[3,1],[5,1],[3,1],[5,1],[5,1],[3,1],[5,1],[3,1],[5,1],[3,1],[5,1],[3,1],[5,1],[5,1],[3,1],[5,1],[3,1],[5,1],[3,1],[5,1],[5,1],[3,1],[5,1],[3,1],[5,1],[3,1],[5,1],[5,1],[3,1],[3,1]]
               Ẏ           - tighten   = [5,1,5,1,3,1,5,1,3,1,5,1,3,1,5,1,5,1,3,1,5,1,3,1,5,1,3,1,5,1,5,1,3,1,5,1,3,1,5,1,3,1,5,1,5,1,3,1,5,1,3,1,5,1,3,1,5,1,3,1,5,1,5,1,3,1,5,1,3,1,5,1,3,1,5,1,5,1,3,1,5,1,3,1,5,1,3,1,5,1,5,1,3,1,3,1]
                Ç          - call the last Link (1) as a monad
                           -           = [1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0]
                 o2        - OR 2      = [1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,2]
                   Ç       - Link 1... = [1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0]
                    +3     - add three = [4,3,4,3,4,3,3,4,3,4,3,4,3,3,4,3,4,3,3,4,3,4,3,4,3,3,4,3,4,3,3,4,3,4,3,4,3,3,4,3,4,3,3,4,3,4,3,4,3,3,4,3,4,3,4,3,3,4,3,4,3,3,4,3,4,3,4,3,3,4,3,4,3,3,4,3,4,3,4,3,3,4,3,4,3,3,4,3,4,3,4,3,3,4,3,4,3,4,3,3,4,3,4,3,3,4,3,4,3,4,3,3,4,3,4,3,3,4,3,4,3,4,3,3,4,3,4,3,3,4,3,4,3,4,3,3,4,3,4,3,4,3,3,4,3,4,3,3,4,3,4,3,4,3,3,4,3,4,3,3,4,3,4,3,4,3,3,4,3,4,3,3,4,3,4,3,4,3,3,4,3,4,3,3,4,3,4,3,4,3,3,4,3,4,3,4,3,3,4,3,4,3,3,4,3,4,3,4,3,3,4,3,4,3,3,4,3,4,3,4,3,3,4,3,4,3,3,4,3,4,3,4,3,3,4,3,4,3,4,3,3,4,3,4,3,3,4,3,4,3,4,3,3,4,3,4,3,3,4,3,4,3,4,3,3,4,3,4,3,3,4,3,4,3,4,3,3,4,3,4,3,4,3,3,4,3,4,3,3,4,3,4,3,3]
                      Ç    - Link 1... = [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0]
                        ȷ  - literal 1000
                       ḣ   - head      = [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1]
                         ¬ - NOT       = [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0]
```

Comment: I've never seen Jelly before!

Comment: Welcome to PPCG :) - it's a golfing language written by one of our moderators, Dennis. Click in the header for it's git-hub page where there is a wiki.

Comment: i promise to get better at posing questions.  i see there's a sandbox and some standard formatting.

Comment: This was pretty much my approach when I started.

Comment: @EsolangingFruit I thought as I was doing it that it could be a fraction doing the repetition... 117/400 it seems!

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8, <s>75</s> <s>64</s> 62 bytes

```java
v->{for(int i=0;i<1e3;)System.out.print((int)(i++*.29253)%2);}
```

Prints the entire sequence without delimiter to save bytes, because they will only be `0` and `1` anyway.

Ports of [*@ETHproductions*' Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/162777/52210), because I doubt I find anything shorter..

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##LY5NDoIwEIX3nmI2Jq2GRiEuTMUbyIbEjXFRSzHFUggtJIZw9joIyUwm8/O@eZUYRFQVnyCNcA5uQttxA6CtV10ppIJsbgGGRhcgyX0uA@U4mzAxnBdeS8jAQgphiK5j2XQE9aDTA9eXo0o4zb/Oq5o1vWdthzsyH1Ci9/sdi8/xKaHbmPIp8IXZ9i@DzBX9f12jMZJ7FL8fT0EXU5ZJYntjVj9T@AE)

**Explanation:**

```java
v->{                     // Method with empty unused parameter and no return-type
  for(int i=0;i<1e3;)    //  Loop `i` in range [0,1000)
    System.out.print(    //   Print:
      (int)(i++*.29253)  //    `i` multiplied with 0.29253,
                         //    and then truncated of their decimal values by casting to int
      %2);}              //    Modulo-2 to result in either 0 or 1
```

---

Old answer returning the resulting array (**75 bytes**):

```java
v->{int i=1000,r[]=new int[i];for(;i-->0;)r[i]=(int)(i*.29253)%2;return r;}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##7VbPS8MwFL77VzwKQqJr6CY7aOjGDh6dh4Igo4eYZZqapTNJq2P0b6/p2sFAhgreLPkB773k@97hg/dlrGRhtnytuWLWwh2TencGILUTZsW4gHkT7hOLFDh6yOUSSkx9svLHb@uYkxzmoCGGugwnO/8WZDyMomhgFmmsxfv@u0zpKjeIyjCcRBQbn4iRL2AkL8joejS@wucjaoQrjAZDq5q2BJviSXmCjqdsGlj7NlHijNTPi5Th4xbFx0ZwJ5a@mQNxuosG7Rru1/fR8JdRj/g3@P8TsddSr6Venb06ey39ELGiRwOfcVcw1Yx7wpEulMJtNdlaJ9YkLxzZeKPglEbBzAhwL2LbXGDZWkwhuESZ90CkcFKRmTFsa4l484gWHazEoOPA0@DxNglugvl9gE@znK58IXJ5a2JQR9D5qqr@BA)

**Explanation:**

```java
v->{                   // Method with empty unused parameter and integer-array return-type
  int i=1000,          //  Index `i`, starting at 1000
      r[]=new int[i];  //  Result-array of size 1000
  for(;i-->0;)         //  Loop `i` in range (1000,0]
    r[i]=              //   Set the item in the array at index `i` to:
      (int)(i*.29253)  //    `i` multiplied with 0.29253,
                       //    and then truncated of their decimal values by casting to int
      %2;              //    Modulo-2 to result in either 0 or 1
  return r;}           //  Return the resulting integer-array
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 96 bytes

I searched for a cellular automaton that looks at the 4 neighbors to the left and produces the walking left pattern seen in the data when you Partition the data into length 7 and keep every third row.

This cellular automaton will run for 29 generations each of which is triplicated, matching the sequence perfectly for characters 1 to 629.  However the sequence starts repeating at the 630th character rather than continuing the observed pattern, so extra code is needed to handle the repeat of the truncated pattern. I generate the main pattern twice to get to 1258 characters.

```
Most@Flatten[{#,#,#}&/@CellularAutomaton[{271,2,-{{4},{3},{2},{1}}},{0,0,0,0,1,1,1},29]]~Table~2
```

Without that glitch we could do it in a shorter 74 bytes.  The 47 is the number of generations needed to get to 1000 characters (this actually goes to 1008=48*7*3)

```
{#,#,#}&/@CellularAutomaton[{271,2,-{{4},{3},{2},{1}}},{0,0,0,0,1,1,1},47]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73ze/uMTBLSexpCQ1L7paWQcIa9X0HZxTc3JKcxKLHEtL8oGK84FyRuaGOkY6utXVJrU61cZAbATEhrW1QNJABwINQbBWx8gyNrYuJDEpJ7XO6H9AUWZeiUPafwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 42 bytes

```python
x=184
while x/629%2:print(x//629%2);x+=184
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v8LW0MKEqzwjMydVoULfzMhS1ciqoCgzr0SjQh/C1bSu0AYp@v8fAA)

Port of [G.B.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/162814/109916)'s answer.

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), <s>13</s> 11 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
í?♫~╘äqx-G▄
```

[Run and debug it at staxlang.xyz!](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=a13f0e7ed48471782d47dc&i=&a=1)

Port to Stax of @ETHproductions's [Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/162777/73884) (before its modification) with some modifications by @recursive to save two bytes.

Comment: You can double the denominator, keep the fractional part, and then round to nearest integer rather than using modulus.  If I'm not mistaken, this also gives [11](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=a13f0e7ed48471782d47dc&i=&a=1)

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>41</s> 33 bytes, port

Thank Rick Hitchcock for 4+ bytes

```javascript
f=i=>i>999?'':(i*.29253&1)+f(-~i)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/e9m@z/NNtPWLtPO0tLSXl3dSiNTS8/I0sjUWM1QUztNQ7cuU/O/dXJ@XnF@TqpeTn66hpuGpuZ/AA)

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 121 bytes, original

```javascript
_=>'8888y888'[s='replace'](/8/g,'aaa3yyy')[s](/y/g,'aaa3aa3')[s](/a/g,34)[s](/./g,t=>(_=+!+_+[]).repeat(t)).slice(3,1003)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYzBCsMgEES/pad1MTUp9hAo5pifkCCLlZAiMUQp@PV2oe0wA493mBe9KftzO8p1T8/QZtOcmWDkVB7YbOAMRyQfYBH92K8dEJGutQLazKr@FfeniJW@f1kxFzMJZ@RFOmkXVPwXqIiCqHLcfBC6uw2Dxvbwac8pBhXTKmaB2D4)

Comment: Save 4 bytes using recursion:  `f=(i=0)=>i<1e3?(i*.29253&1)+f(i+1):''`

Answer (score 2):

## [Z80Golf](https://github.com/lynn/z80golf), 27 bytes

```
00000000: 018d 2b7b 1f1f e601 f630 ff09 3001 1313  ..+{.....0..0...
00000010: 7bfe 9220 ee7a fe04 20e9 76              {.. .z.. .v
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYwxCsMwEAT7vGL7wLEnGcnybyJy58bgzoX8eFlO0mRYFqaZNnPdN@@dPxZQ5zdCzRXq6rBEhadIuLMgcqhGjYDI85QbfiaPb0FHI1c3lBAIs/yCGycEWkFO@GMEIO2@o/cL)

Translated from this C code:

```
for (n = 0; n >> 16 != 1170; n += 11149 + 65536)
    putchar('0'|n>>18&1);
```

Disassembly:

```
  ld bc, 11149
loop:
  ld a, e
  rra
  rra
  and 1
  or '0'
  rst $38           ; putchar
  add hl, bc        ; Add 11149 to n = DEHL.
  jr nc, just_one   ; Add 65536 to n, possibly with carry from low 16 bits.
  inc de
just_one:
  inc de
  ld a, e
  cp 1170 & 255
  jr nz, loop
  ld a, d
  cp 1170 >> 8
  jr nz, loop
  halt
```

This is essentially a fixed-point arithmetic approach: (11149 + 65536) / 2<sup>18</sup> ≈ 0.29253, the constant used by other answers.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 13 bytes

```js
A³Ç*.29#ý f u
A³             // Given 10³,
  Ç            // map over it as a range, returning the given number
   *.29253     // times the constant,
           f u // floored and mod-2.
```

Japt version of [ETHproduction's Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/162777/16484).
Bug fixed thanks to [Oliver](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61613/oliver).

[Try it here.](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=QbPHKi4yOSP9IGYgdQ==&input=)

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 17 bytes

```
2|<.0.29253*i.1e3
```

A J port of ETHproduction's Jelly answer.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/36jGRs9Az8jSyNRYK1PPMNX4f2pyRr5CvKlBbAymHAA)

Answer (score 1):

## C, <s>55</s> <s>53</s> 52 bytes

```c
f(i,j){for(i=0;j=.29253*i,i++-1e3;)putchar(j%2+48);}
```

Port of Kevin Cruijssen's Java [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/162805/79343). Try it online [here](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI1MnS7M6Lb9II9PWwDrLVs/I0sjUWCtTJ1NbW9cw1dhas6C0JDkjsUgjS9VI28RC07r2f25iZp4GUJMGiAMA).

Thanks to [vazt](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78276/vazt) for golfing 2 bytes and to [Jonathan Frech](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/73111/jonathan-frech) for golfing one more.

Ungolfed version:

```c
f(i, j) { // function taking two dummy arguments (implicitly int) and implicitly returning an unused int
    for(i = 0; j = .29253*i, i++ - 1e3; ) //  loop 1000 times, multiply i with 0.29253, truncating to an integer
        putchar(j % 2 + 48);  // modulo the truncated integer by 2, yielding 0 or 1, then convert to ASCII (48 is ASCII code for '0') and print
}
```

Comment: `i` is initialized to 0 since it's global, so you can remove the `i=0` from the for-loop initializer to save 3 bytes. Also if you introduce a second variable (as a parameter to `f()`) and assign `i++*.29253` to it, you can avoid the cast and save another 2 bytes: `i;f(j){for(;i<1e3;)printf("%d",(j=i++*.29253)%2);}` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/TOk0jS7M6Lb9IwzrTxjDV2FqzoCgzryRNQ0k1RUlHI8s2U1tbS8/I0sjUWFPVSNO69n9uYmaehqZCNRdnmoamNVftfwA "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: @vazt Yes, `i` is initialized to 0 in the beginning, but if we want to call this function more than once, that's not good enough. Using `j` to avoid the cast is a great golf, thank you.

Comment: [52 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI1MnS7M6Lb9II9PWwDrLVs/I0sjUWCtTJ1NbW9cw1dhas6C0JDkjsUgjS9VI28RC07r2f25iZp4GUJMGiAMA).

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 13 bytes

```
Ｅφ§01×·²⁹²⁵³ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM3sUDD0MDAQEfBscQzLyW1QkPJwFBJRyEkMze1WEPPyNLI1FhHIVMTCKz///@vW5YDAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
 φ              Predefined variable 1000
Ｅ               Map over implicit range
            ι   Current value
      ·²⁹²⁵³    Literal constant `0.29253`
     ×          Multiply
   01           Literal string `01`
  §             Cyclically index
                Implicitly print each result on its own line
```

Thanks to @ASCII-only for allowing indexing to accept floats which are cast to integer (and then automatically reduced modulo 2 in this case).

Answer (score 1):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 63 bytes

```
/b/000111//A/b1b//B/b0b//C/0BA1//X/CACACACA0bCBCBCB/0bXXCBXCAC0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcjBCcBQCATRknYtQW3C618I5JCb/WMM4R0Gpp/T99UzEEiaGeCQCQiImwTD9xbSf1TGB1RVRu3jzAs)

Answer (score 1):

## Deadfish~, 1301 bytes

```
{iiiii}ddccccicccdccccicccdccccicccdccciccccdccciccccdccciccccdcccicccdccccicccdccccicccdccciccccdccciccccdccciccccdcccicccdccccicccdccccicccdccciccccdccciccccdccciccccdcccicccdccccicccdccccicccdccciccccdccciccccdccciccccdcccicccdccccicccdccccicccdccccicccdccciccccdccciccccdcccicccdccccicccdccccicccdccccicccdccciccccdccciccccdcccicccdccccicccdccccicccdccccicccdccciccccdccciccccdcccicccdccccicccdccccicccdccccicccdccciccccdccciccccdccciccccdcccicccdccccicccdccccicccdccciccccdccciccccdccciccccdcccicccdccccicccdccccicccdccciccccdccciccccdccciccccdcccicccdccccicccdccccicccdccciccccdccciccccdccciccccdcccicccdccccicccdccccicccdccccicccdccciccccdccciccccdcccicccdccccicccdccccicccdccccicccdccciccccdccciccccdcccicccdccccicccdccccicccdccccicccdccciccccdccciccccdcccicccdccccicccdccccicccdccccicccdccciccccdccciccccdcccicccdccccicccdccccicccdccccicccdccciccccdccciccccdccciccccdcccicccdccccicccdccccicccdccciccccdccciccccdccciccccdcccicccdccccicccdccccicccdccciccccdccciccccdccciccccdcccicccdccccicccdccccicccdccciccccdccciccccdccciccccdcccicccdccccicccdccccicccdccccicccdccciccccdccciccccdcccicccdccccicccdccccicccdccccicccdccciccccdccciccccdcccicccdccccicccdccccicccdccccicccdccciccccdccciccccdcccicccdccccicccdccccicccdccccicccdccciccccdccciccccdccciccccdcccicccdccccicccdccccicccdccciccccdccciccccdc
```